# NOT Super Administrator as default

Tags: administrator, joomla.com

I am new to Joomla, just added a website with a new account there today.

By default I am the Administrator (not super) and missing some of the functionalities.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What functionalities are you missing? Does your hosting have the minimum requiremnts?

Comment: I cannot edit the template, I have standard free hosting on Joomla

Comment: If you are on a demojoomla site, then some features are restricted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you've signed up for an account on [Joomla.com](http://joomla.com). This service has a slightly different setup than a "normal" Joomla installation (downloaded from [joomla.org](http://joomla.org) and installed on your own hosting account).

As described in the [tutorials](http://www.tutorials.joomla.com/no-category/34-joomla-com-admin):

> None of the core Joomla content management function is limited for the
>   Joomla.com users: articles, media, users, menus, components and
>   extensions can be edited as in a standard Joomla CMS. However, **no
>   Superusers are allowed оn Joomla.com websites**. Тhe installation of the
>   extensions and templates is restricted and the users cannot edit
>   server configuration information.

Further differences between Joomla.com and Joomla.org can be found on http://www.tutorials.joomla.com/basics/16-joomla-com-vs-joomla-org

Good luck with Joomla, I'm sure you'll like it. And don't hesitate to ask if you have another question.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are using the free version of Joomla where some functionality is restricted. For example you only have Administrator access.

For full functionality you can [upgrade](http://tutorials.joomla.com/dashboard/31-upgrade) to a paid SiteGround account with your own domain name.

You can also [export a joomla.com website](http://tutorials.joomla.com/dashboard/35-exporting-your-joomla-com-website) via the [joomla.com](http://joomla.com) dashboard. The export file includes the website files and database which are sufficient to recreate the website on an alternative hosting server.